# Scriptable object only work when opened in the assets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

SO I have a script that fetch all the objects of type `skinsbgcreator` (scriptable object instances). Here is the script :

```
doges = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(skinsbgcreator)) as skinsbgcreator[];
```

When I launch my game just after having opened the editor, my scriptable objects are not detected by this script, like the array `doge` is empty.

But once I open each of them in the assets just by clicking on them, then they are detected because my array is full. It's like if They only compile when I open them the inspector. Thanks

Comment: This function can return any type of Unity object that **is loaded**.

Comment: @shingo but how to load?

Comment: e.g, clicking on the assets, or having them referenced in the opened scene, etc.

Comment: @shingo clicking them doesn't work when I build, and how to reference them in the scene ?

Comment: Why using `Resources` at all and not just have a `public skinsbgcreator[] doges;` in one of your components?

Comment: @derHugo I wanted to make easy to add a new skin for the updates of the game

Comment: If you update your game, you'll reference them anyway. You'll still need to track them right? For example, if you add a new doge it will have a different name, possibly different skins or meshes, even sounds, stats and so on. So just as you track them that way, just reference them directly. using `Resources` is fine for a bit of dynamic content but it has tons of limitations and most times, you won't need it even if you *think* you do. And as far as I know, if you click on them so they get loaded and then build, it should work fine. It's the same in the Editor as well and it's normal.